# racket scheme get-argb-pixels

Tags: scheme, racket

I have a 32 by 32 pixel png file.  I'm trying to read the values within it using get-argb-pixels.

My code is as follows:

```
#lang racket/gui

(require racket/gui/base)

(define floor (make-object bitmap% "C:\\floortile.png"))

(define pixels (make-bytes (* 32 32 4)))

(send floor get-argb-pixels 0 0 32 32 pixels)
```

After executing the code I was expecting a series of 8 bit values to be contained within pixels.  Examining pixels gives me the following output:

```
> pixels
#"\377\2148\30\377\214<\30\377\234E\30\377\245I\30\377\245I\30\377\234E\30\377\234A\30\377\224A\30\377\224A\30\377\234A\30\377\245E\30\377\255M\30\377\224A\30\377\234E\30\377\245I\30\377\224A\30\377\234E\30\377\234E\30\377\255I\30\377\245I\30\377\245E\30\377\234A\30\377\234E\30\377\234A\30\377\245I\30\377\265Q\30\377\306]\30\377\306Y\30\377\275U\30\377\265Q\30\377\306a!\377\306]!\377\214<\30\377\224A\30\377\224A\30\377\245I\30\377\255M\30\377\255M\30\377\245I\30\377\234E\30\377\234E\30\377\245I\30\377\245I\30\377\255M\30\377\234A\30\377\245E\30\377\265M\30\377\234A\30\377\245I\30\377\245E\30\377\245E\30\377\255M\30\377\245I\30\377\245E\30\377\234A\30\377\234E\30\377\255I\30\377\275U\30\377\306]\30\377\326e!\377\336e!\377\265Q\30\377\326e!\377\326a!\377{8\30\377\224E\30\377\224A\30\377\245I\30\377\245I\30\377\255M\30\377\255M\30\377\255I\30\377\245I\30\377\245I\30\377\245I\30\377\265Q\30\377\214<\30\377\245I\30\377\255M\30\377\265M\30\377\255M\30\377\265M\30\377\265M\30\377\245I\30\377\234E\30\377\234E\30\377\234E\30\377\245E\30\377\275Q\30\377\306]!\377\316a!\377\336i!\377\357q!\377\275Y\30\377\316e!\377\347i!\377k0\20\377\2048\30\377\224A\30\377\265U!\377\234E\30\377\234E\30\377\245M\30\377\255M\30\377\255M\30\377\255I\30\377\255M\30\377\265M\30\377\2048\20\377\245I\30\377\245I\30\377\306Y!\377\265Q\30\377\255M\30\377\265Q\30\377\265M\30\377\265M\30\377\255I\30\377\265Q\30\377\265M\30\377\275U\30\377\316a!\377\326i!\377\347m!\377\367\216)\377\347y)\377\336m)\377\326]!\377s0\20\377{8\30\377{4\20\377\2048\30\377s4\20\377\2048\30\377{4\20\377\214<\30\377\224A\30\377\234A\30\377\224A\30\377\224A\30\377\214<\30\377\2148\30\377\224<\30\377\234A\30\377\214<\30\377\234E\30\377\245I\30\377\265Q\30\377\255M\30\377\265U\30\377\306Y\30\377\265Q\30\377\275U\30\377\326a!\377\336i!\377\347u!\377\357\206)\377\326q)\377\326i)\377\347i!\377s0\20\377{4\20\377{4\30\377\214<\30\377s4\20\377\2048\30\377s4\20\377\224A\30\377\224A\30\377\224<\30\377\234A\30\377\245E\30\377\234E\30\377\234I\30\377\234E\30\377\245I\30\377\245I\30\377\245I\30\377\265Q\30\377\306]\30\377\255M\30\377\255M\30\377\255M\30\377\255M\30\377\275U\30\377\255M\30\377\275U\30\377\316a!\377\306]!\377\326i!\377\367\206)\377\377})\377s4\30\377k,\20\377k,\20\377s4\30\377{4\20\377\2048\30\377c(\20\377\2048\20\377\234A\30\377\245E\30\377\245E\30\377\255I\30\377\245I\30\377\245I\30\377\245I\30\377\265Q\30\377\275U!\377\255M\30\377\255M\30\377\255M\30\377\255M\30\377\275U\30\377\306]!\377\275U\30\377\255M\30\377\306Y!\377\306]!\377\316e!\377\316a!\377\326i!\377\347y)\377\367y)\377c(\20\377c,\20\377k,\20\377s0\20\377s4\20\377\2048\30\377\214<\30\377{4\20\377\214<\30\377\234E\30\377\234A\30\377\245I\30\377\255M\30\377\255M\30\377\255M\30\377\265Q\30\377\265M\30\377\265Q\30\377\265Q\30\377\255M\30\377\265U\30\377\255M\30\377\265Q\30\377\265U\30\377\265U\30\377\265Q\30\377\306Y\30\377\316a!\377\306a!\377\326i!\377\347y)\377\367\202)\377c,\20\377k,\20\377s0\20\377s0\20\377{8\30\377\214<\30\377s,\20\377s0\20\377\214<\30\377\234A\30\377\245E\30\377\255M\30\377\255M\30\377\245I\30\377\255M\30\377\275U\30\377\265U\30\377\265Q\30\377\265Q\30\377\275Y\30\377\255M\30\377\255I\30\377\275U\30\377\275Y!\377\275Y\30\377\265U\30\377\306Y!\377\326e!\377\336m!\377\336q!\377\347})\377\357\202)\377s0\20\377s4\30\377s4\30\377\2048\30\377\234E\30\377\2048\20\377\2148\30\377c(\20\377\2048\30\377\214<\30\377\234E\30\377\265Q\30\377\265Q\30\377\255M\30\377\265M\30\377\316a!\377\275U\30\377\275Y\30\377\265Q\30\377\265Q\30\377\265Q\30\377\265Q\30\377\255M\30\377\275Y\30\377\275Y!\377\275Y\30\377\275U\30\377\316a!\377\347q)\377\367\202)\377\357})\377\347y)\377k0\20\377\2048\30\377{4\30\377\2048\30\377\214A\30\377\2048\30\377\2044\30\377s4\20\377k,\20\377\2048\30\377\224A\30\377\245I\30\377\234A\30\377\234E\30\377\255Q\30\377\275U\30\377\306Y!\377\265Q\30\377\255Q\30\377\265U\30\377\265U\30\377\265Q\30\377\265Q\30\377\316e!\377\316a!\377\306]!\377\275Y!\377\306]!\377\336i!\377\357})\377\367\202)\377\336u)\377k0\20\377s0\30\377\2048\30\377\204<\30\377\204<\30\377\2048\30\377\2048\30\377\214<\30\377s4\20\377\2048\30\377\214A\30\377\224A\30\377\224E\30\377\234E\30\377\265Q\30\377\275U\30\377\306Y\30\377\255M\30\377\265Q\30\377\265Q\30\377\316]!\377\326e!\377\316]!\377\336m)\377\336i)\377\316e!\377\306a!\377\326e!\377\367y)\377\367})\377\367\2061\377\367\2061\377s4\30\377{8\30\377{8\30\377\214<\30\377\214<\30\377\204<\30\377{4\20\377\214<\30\377\214<\30\377\214<\30\377\234E\30\377\234E\30\377\224E\30\377\234E\30\377\245M\30\377\275U\30\377\275U!\377\275U\30\377\306]!\377\306]!\377\316a!\377\326i)\377\347u)\377\326e!\377\347q)\377\336q)\377\326i)\377\326i)\377\347q)\377\367\202)\377\367})\377\367\2061\377{8\30\377s4\30\377{8\30\377\214<\30\377\224A\30\377\234E\30\377\214<\30\377\214<\30\377\224A\30\377\224<\30\377\234E\30\377\255M\30\377\245I\30\377\245I\30\377\255M\30\377\265U\30\377\306]!\377\306]!\377\316a!\377\316e!\377\326e!\377\347m)\377\316e!\377\306]!\377\347u)\377\347u)\377\336m)\377\316e)\377\336q)\377\357y)\377\367\202)\377\367\2021\377{4\30\377s4\30\377\2048\30\377\214A\30\377\224A\30\377\224A\30\377\224E\30\377\214<\30\377\214<\30\377\245I\30\377\234A\30\377\255M\30\377\255M\30\377\245I\30\377\255M\30\377\255Q\30\377\306]!\377\306]!\377\316a!\377\316a!\377\316a!\377\347u)\377\326e!\377\275Y!\377\265Y!\377\336m)\377\306a)\377\336m)\377\336m)\377\326e)\377\347q)\377\336q)\377s0\30\377s0\30\377\204<\30\377\224A\30\377\224E\30\377\234I\30\377\234E\30\377\234E\30\377\255M\30\377\234E\30\377{4\30\377\224<\30\377\245M\30\377\255I\30\377\234A\30\377\255M\30\377\245E\30\377\255M\30\377\265Q\30\377\245I\30\377\275U\30\377\255I\30\377\234A\30\377\224E\30\377\265U\30\377\234I\30\377\224E\30\377\245M\30\377\234M!\377\224A\30\377\234I\30\377\224E\30\377k0\20\377s0\20\377{4\30\377\214<\30\377\224E\30\377\234E\30\377\245I\30\377\234I\30\377\245I\30\377\214<\30\377\214<\30\377\255M\30\377\265Q!\377\265Q!\377\255M\30\377\306]!\377\316a)\377\326e)\377\326a!\377\316]!\377\265Q\30\377\326a!\377\255M\30\377\204<\20\377\245M\30\377\234I\30\377\245M\30\377\275]!\377\234I\30\377\255U!\377\265Y!\377\245M!\377c(\20\377k,\20\377k0\20\377\2048\30\377\224A\30\377\224E\30\377\234I\30\377\245I\30\377\275Y!\377\234E\30\377\245I\30\377\245I\30\377\265U!\377\265Q!\377\265Q!\377\306]!\377\306]!\377\316a!\377\316a!\377\336e)\377\326a!\377\316]!\377\265Q\30\377\224A\30\377\234I\30\377\275]!\377\265Y!\377\275Y!\377\275Y!\377\265U!\377\265])\377\275])\377s4\30\377c(\20\377k,\20\377s0\20\377\214A\30\377\224E\30\377\234E\30\377\306]!\377\234I\30\377\224A\30\377\265U!\377\245I\30\377\265Q!\377\265Q!\377\265M!\377\255M\30\377\306]!\377\306Y!\377\306]!\377\306]!\377\326a)\377\336i)\377\275U!\377\224A\30\377\224A\30\377\306a!\377\275]!\377\275Y!\377\275]!\377\275])\377\275Y!\377\275Y!\377s0\20\377k,\20\377s0\20\377\2048\30\377\214<\30\377\224E\30\377\234E\30\377\245M\30\377\224A\30\377\214A\30\377\245M\30\377\265Q!\377\275U!\377\255I\30\377\245I\30\377\245I\30\377\275U!\377\306Y!\377\275Y!\377\306]!\377\306]!\377\265Q\30\377\255M\30\377\224A\30\377\204<\30\377\255Q\30\377\245M\30\377\255Q!\377\265Y!\377\275]!\377\265Y!\377\275Y!\377s0\20\377k0\20\377{0\20\377\2048\30\377\204<\30\377\204<\30\377\214<\30\377\224A\30\377\316a!\377\245I\30\377\234E\30\377\245I\30\377\265U!\377\265Q!\377\265Q!\377\255M!\377\275U!\377\275U!\377\275U!\377\275Q!\377\255I\30\377\255M\30\377\255Q\30\377\234E\30\377{4\30\377\224A\30\377\214<\30\377\275Y!\377\275Y!\377\275]!\377\255Q!\377\255Q!\377k,\20\377k,\20\377s0\20\377\2044\30\377{4\20\377{4\30\377\2048\30\377\245M\30\377\265U!\377\245I\30\377\214A\30\377\275Y!\377\234A\30\377\255M\30\377\265Q!\377\245M!\377\265U!\377\275Q!\377\245I\30\377\245I\30\377\245M\30\377\265Q!\377\255Q!\377\255M\30\377\214<\30\377\245I\30\377\255Q!\377\306]!\377\306]!\377\275U!\377\265U!\377\255Q!\377c(\20\377Z(\20\377c(\20\377k,\20\377{8\30\377{4\30\377\214<\30\377\214A\30\377\234E\30\377\245I\30\377\245M\30\377\214<\30\377s0\30\377\255M!\377\255I!\377\255M!\377\255M!\377\265Q!\377\265Q!\377\255M!\377\265Q\30\377\245I\30\377\255I\30\377\306Y!\377\275Y!\377\214A\30\377\255Q\30\377\275]!\377\306])\377\306]!\377\255U!\377\255Q!\377k0\30\377k0\20\377k,\20\377s0\20\377s0\20\377s4\30\377{4\30\377\214<\30\377\245I\30\377\224A\30\377\306Y!\377\234A\30\377s0\20\377\245I\30\377\255M!\377\255M!\377\255M!\377\255M!\377\255Q!\377\265M!\377\316]!\377\245E\30\377\316]!\377\306Y!\377\275U!\377{8\30\377\255Q!\377\265Y!\377\275]!\377\275Y!\377\275Y!\377\255Q!\377k0\20\377c,\20\377k,\20\377s0\20\377{4\30\377s0\20\377{4\30\377{4\30\377\2048\30\377\245I\30\377\234E\30\377\234E\30\377k,\20\377\214<\30\377\224A\30\377\245M\30\377\214<\30\377\224E\30\377\214<\30\377\214<\30\377\214<\30\377\245I\30\377\234E\30\377\224A\30\377\224A\30\377k,\20\377\224A\30\377\265Q!\377\265Y!\377\265U!\377\265Y!\377\275Y!\377c(\20\377c,\20\377k,\20\377s0\20\377k,\20\377k0\20\377\2048\30\377\234A\30\377\214<\30\377\224A\30\377\245I\30\377\245I\30\377k0\20\377{4\20\377\214<\30\377\214A\30\377\214<\30\377\204<\30\377\2048\30\377\234I\30\377\224A\30\377\214<\30\377\234E\30\377\234E\30\377\255M\30\377\224A\30\377{8\30\377\255Q!\377\265U!\377\255U!\377\255U!\377\265U!\377c(\20\377k,\20\377s0\20\377s0\20\377{4\20\377\2048\30\377\2048\30\377\2048\30\377\224A\30\377\245M\30\377\245E\30\377\234E\30\377{4\20\377Z(\20\377k0\30\377{8\30\377\2048\30\377\214A\30\377\224A\30\377\234I\30\377\214<\30\377\224A\30\377\224A\30\377\234E\30\377\245I\30\377\255M\30\377{8\30\377\214A\30\377\255U!\377\255U!\377\245Q!\377\265U!\377c,\20\377c(\20\377k,\20\377Z$\20\377Z$\20\377Z(\20\377c(\20\377k,\20\377k,\20\377c(\20\377c(\20\377c,\20\377k0\20\377R \20\377c,\20\377s4\30\377{4\30\377\204<\30\377\2048\30\377\214A\30\377\224A\30\377\224A\30\377\234I\30\377\234I\30\377\224A\30\377\245I\30\377\224E\30\377\2048\30\377\255U!\377\255Q!\377\265U!\377\265Y)\377J \20\377J\34\20\377Z(\20\377k,\20\377k(\20\377c(\20\377R \20\377c(\20\377k,\20\377s0\20\377k0\20\377k0\20\377c,\20\377Z(\20\377c,\20\377s4\20\377s4\20\377\2048\30\377\2048\20\377\2048\30\377\224A\30\377\214A\30\377\234I\30\377\245I\30\377\234I\30\377\245M!\377\245M\30\377\204<\30\377\234M!\377\245Q!\377\265U!\377\255U!\377c,\20\377c,\20\377c(\20\377c(\20\377c(\20\377c(\20\377c(\20\377k,\20\377k,\20\377k,\20\377k0\20\377s4\20\377s0\30\377\204<\30\377c(\20\377s4\20\377s4\30\377{4\20\377{4\30\377\204<\30\377\224A\30\377\234E\30\377\234E\30\377\234E\30\377\234E\30\377\245I\30\377\245I\30\377\224E\30\377\204<\30\377\245Q!\377\255Q!\377\347\327\326\377R$\20\377k,\20\377c(\20\377c(\20\377c(\20\377c(\20\377Z$\20\377c(\20\377c(\20\377k,\20\377k,\20\377k,\20\377s0\20\377{4\30\377\204<\30\377k,\20\377s4\20\377s4\20\377{8\30\377\2048\20\377\214<\30\377\214<\30\377\214A\30\377\234E\30\377\234E\30\377\224A\30\377\224E\30\377\224E\30\377s4\30\377\214A\30\377\265\206s\377\377\377\377\377c,\20\377k,\30\377k0\20\377k,\20\377c(\20\377Z$\20\377Z(\20\377Z$\20\377c(\20\377c(\20\377c(\20\377k,\20\377k0\20\377{4\30\377{8\30\377k,\20\377c,\20\377k0\20\377s0\20\377{8\30\377\2048\30\377\2048\30\377\214<\30\377\224A\30\377\224E\30\377\214<\30\377\214A\30\377\234I\30\377{8!\377\214M1\377\377\373\377\377\377\377\377"
```

This doesn't look like a series of 8 bit values to me.  Have I done something wrong or am I misinterpreting the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get  *byte string* which is an efficient representation of a block of arbitrary data.  You can inspect it with `bytes-ref` etc, or if you want a list of byte values, use `bytes->list`.